# How to add a block to magento Sales Emails in admin

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

I want to add a section/block very similar to order or order comments to the sales Emails page in magento administrator, but I never found the template file related to it. Anyone please explain or paste a link so I can figure out how the page is processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it I included the same XML in the code/Mage/Sales/etc/system.xml as the order, order comment sections.

1. Open the system.xml file.
2. Search the sales_email.
3. All the XML between this tag is related to the sales_email page of Admin.
4. Copy a XML tag and modify the as you required.

The fields and values in the new block will be saved to the core_config_data. From there you can query the fields values.